# Read INI file to initialize variables

Tags: perl, ini

I have to write a number of Perl scripts, where each script tests a distinct Unix application command.
I want to put all my variables in a .ini file with each section being a distinct command.
Sample of INI file:

```
[Sec2]
item1=xx
item3=yy
[usermgr]
domain=/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/Auto/testDomain/PlatformConfigGD
msgs=user .* was added,usermgr completed successfully
group=Admin
grouplbl=Admin
```

My iniRead function:

```
sub iniRead
 {
  my $ini = $_[0];
  my $conf;
 my $section;
  open (INI, "$ini") || die "Can't open $ini: $!\n";
    while (<INI>) {
        chomp;
        if (/^\s*\[\s*(.+?)\s*\]\s*$/) {
          $section = $1;
        }

        if ( /^\s*([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/ ) {
          $conf->{$section}->{$1} = $2;
        }
    }
  close (INI);
  return $conf;
}
```

Inside my script I am adding lines like below to initialize the variables:

```
my $conf = iniRead("/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/test/test.ini");
my $domain= $conf->{"dimensionMgr"}->{"domain"};
my $dim = $conf->{"dimensionMgr"}->{"dim"};
```

Is there a way to initialize the variables inside each script with fewer lines of code?

Comment: I cannot use any external modules from CPAN as they are restricted inside the organization

Comment: Make those modules internal or go and find a different organization to work for

Comment: @MohimaChaudhuri If you can write files to disk, you can use modules... Modules are just code. Why people get this hangup is really hard to understand sometimes.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI

Comment: @TLP that's almost certainly a change management thing. The techy knows the truth, but the people approving your change think Windows and 'Installing' which makes far reaching system changes, and thus must be checked, tested, analysed etc.

Comment: Why do you have to "initialize the variables inside each script" at all? You've already got everything you need in a hashref!

Comment: You can literally copy and paste the code from `Config::Tiny` into a local module called `Company::Config`, or even pack it directly into your software inline.

Comment: Thanks everyone , I made a local copy of Config::IniFiles, since I do not have root permission

Comment: @MohimaChaudhuri with for instance https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib you can install any module without root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I made a local copy of Config::IniFiles, since I do not have root permission – Mohima Chaudhuri

with for instance [metacpan.org/pod/local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) you can install any module without root permissions.
                    – bolav